# why i cannot place one equal = instead of two ==

Tags: javascript, equality

when i put one '=' instead of two or three equal character between two elements,the program goes wrong and it doesn't work properly
i'd like to know why i can't make two element of different types equal to each other by one equal sign(=) but i can do with three or two but they aren't same type
look at my code:

```
const progress=document.getElementById('progress')
const prev=document.getElementById('prev')
const next=document.getElementById('next')
const circles=document.querySelectorAll('.circle')

let currentActive=1

next.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    currentActive++
  
    if(currentActive>circles.length){
        currentActive=circles.length
    }
    update()
})

prev.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    currentActive--
    if(currentActive<1){
        currentActive=1

    }
    update ()


})

function update(){
circles.forEach((circle,idx)=> {
    
    if(idx<currentActive){
        circle.classList.add('active')
    }else{
        circle.classList.remove('active')
    }
    
})

    const actives=document.querySelectorAll('.active')
    progress.style.width=(actives.length - 1) / (circles.length - 1) * 100 + '%'
    
    if(currentActive=== 1){
        prev.disabled=true
    }else if(currentActive === circles.length){
        next.disabled=true

    }else{
        prev.disabled=false
        next.disabled=false
    }
}
```

current active is a variable which contains number and circles.length is an element which contains number.
although they aren't same type,when i put three equals,program runs correctly but when i put one equal it doesn't.
it should be opposite because they can't be same type.

Comment: A single `=` is an assignment, two `==` are a comparison. Two completely different things. Therefore your question is very confusing

Comment: I think you're confusing `=` (assignment), `==` (loose equality), and `===` (strict equality).

Comment: If you're using `=` for assignment, how do you not see the necessity for a different operator to perform equality testing? Assignment and equality tests are allowed in overlapping contexts, they need different operators.

Answer (score 0):

= is an assignment operator, it will assign right hand value to left hand variable, on the other side == or === are comparison operator which checks whether LHS is equal to RHS or not. So if you are comparing the values, use == or ===.

Note:
== -> It just checks the value.
=== -> It checks object type and value

Comment: so you are saying when we use === or == it only compares them and it doesn't assign anything?